# Solve the differential equation y^2+y'^2=1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation $y^2+y'^2=1$.

Could you give me some hints? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a first-order nonlinear ODE we could try seperation of variables:

$y' = \sqrt{1 -y^2 } $

$\Rightarrow \int \frac{y'}{\sqrt{1 -y^2 }}~dx = \int -1 ~dx$

Then use trig identities for LHS.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: there are some obvious trigonometric solutions.